# What challenges will I face if I install Pfsense on my home router?

Tags: networking, linux, routing, freebsd, pfsense

In my cybersecurity course, we installed a lab in VirtualBox with Pfsense (Bridged Adapter) and several other VMs (Connected to Pfsense's internal network adapters). It was a success.

My question is, what challenges will I face if I do this on my home router?

Comment: Nothing is known about your home router and if it can run pfsense in the first place. Check [the hardware requirements first](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/install/installing-pfsense.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your home router is probably a specialized hardware gadget running on a non-Intel CPU (probably an ARM of some kind), with very limited RAM.

So, the main challenge will be that of getting a match between your PF distribution and the hardware. This might require recompilation, tweaking, or [sourcing different hardware](https://www.pfsense.org/products/).

Other than that, I'd say that after the course, the main hurdles are behind you. Congratulations :-)